# Post/Redirect/Get pattern and sticky forms

Tags: php, forms, post-redirect-get

I'm using the Post/Redirect/Get pattern on a form of mine. I've never used this approach before and I'm trying to figure something out:

Normally, I always just display the posted form again when there are validation errors and display POST values in the form (sticky form). However, with the PRG pattern, the form is displayed after a redirect, so there aren't any POST values.

So my question is, **how can I implement the PRG pattern and still have sticky forms?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you redirecting if validation fails? You should redirect only on success, and keep your sticky form on failure.

Comment: Yeah I just had this obvious revelation pop up in my mind. I shouldn't be up coding this late, my mind isn't functioning too well at this hour. Thanks Max.